# How can I turn up the brightness of my notebook lcd in linux?

Tags: linux, laptop, command-line, lcd

No matter if I use Kubuntu or Pardus (both use the powerdevil backend), the maximum 100% monitor brightness level that they allow me to set, is not what my screen can do.

When I boot up the notebook or return from suspend-to-ram the screen is really really bright, and then gets dimmed immediately.

The Fn + brigthness up/down shortcuts or the gui of powerdevil won't let me restore the true maximum brightness, just the 100%, which are moderately dim.

Is there a command or some other cli-magic I can use to truly get my lcd back to the brightness it is supposed to be?

Comment: Does this happen only when the notebook is on batteries?

Comment: no, the notebook is on A/C.

Also it is a U3s, having 2 graphics card. It is currently running on a:
lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the monitor brightness through the console with xbacklight ([man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight))

Comment: thanks for the answer, xbacklight also shows 100%, even though it is pretty dim...